# C# File Not Found For Custom Font in Visual Studio Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts

I'm relatively new to C#, so pretty much I have a folder included in my WinForms project that contains a custom font. The font works absolutely fine upon launch of the application, but in the actual designer on Visual Studio itself, the custom control can't be loaded (as the path I'm using is different when in the designer). Here is the code I use to locate the font from the resources folder:

```
string leadDirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath, "Resources" + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "Roboto-Regular.ttf");
```

The directory which is used in the designer is "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Resources\Roboto-Regular.ttf", and obviously it throws a file not found exception in the method.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: run in Debug, check the content `leadDirectory` and the actual path of you font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not opening the directory you think you are opening. Check in debug mode what `System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath` actually *is*.

To fully understand what goes wrong here, you should understand how running programs from the command prompt work. You have the command prompt, and on that prompt, you see your "current path" is set to a certain directory. Normally, this indicates you want to do stuff in that particular directory, but you can launch a program that is anywhere on your system by giving the full path to launch. However, this will *not* make your command prompt switch to the path of that launched application. You will still remain in that same folder, despite running a program that is located somewhere else. This folder is the "startup path" that you are using. As you can imagine, it has no relation at all to where you are trying to look for that `Resources` folder.

Despite having evolved to a graphical user interface, the way programs launch still works the same way as it did in DOS, so this distinction remains.

In Windows Forms, you can use `Application.ExecutablePath` to get the full path and filename to your exe file, so if you use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` on that, you have the base path you want. In case your program would *not* be a WinForms application, you can instead use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location`, from the `System.Reflection` namespace.