# Why does File.ReadAllText in a service reset its directory to "C:\Windows\System32"?

Tags: c#, httpserver

I have created a **service** that acts also an HTTPServer, I have written html files and stored them in a folder in the same working directory, (say 
 `E:\My_project\Pages\home.html` )
I have a Library.cs file in `E:\My_project\` . In my code I have this line,

```
string content = File.ReadAllText("Pages/home.html");
```

While I try to read this line, I get the following error,

```
mscorlib: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\Pages\home.html'
```

Earlier, it worked for some other pages, when I hardcoded the home page alone and read other pages like 404.html from those directory. Now that I have added the home page also to the pages folder, I get this error.

My Question is how to overcome this error and why does windows go to `C:\Windows\System32` rather than looking in the same directory as the file.

NOTE: Yes, I have used threading, the service uses multiple threads.

Code:

> Library.cs

```
public static List<Route> GetRoutes() {
        List<Route> routes = new List<Route>();
        string content = File.ReadAllText("Pages/home.html");
        routes.Add(new Route
        {
            Name = "Hello Handler",
            UrlRegex = @"^/$",
            Method = "GET",
            Callable = (HttpRequest request) =>
            {
                return HttpBuilder.GetHome();
            }
        });
        return routes;
}
```

Comment: What about ``/Pages/home.html``

Comment: Relative paths use the current working directory. Assuming *any* current working directory in the presence of multithreading and complex components is a recipe for disaster. Just say No.

Comment: @Joelty that resets to C:/Pages/home.html

Comment: Because the current directory for a service is `C:\WINDOWS\system32` by design.

Comment: @JLe how do I overcome this? Any way to embed the resource pages with the service?

Comment: Never assume that the folder your files are in is the folder your program will run in. You can find some information in https://stackoverflow.com/a/49106793/395685

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service applications are like regular Windows applications in their understanding of "current directory".  When you want to access a file and pass a relative name, your application tries to find the file by searching in:
1. The directory where an application is loaded. 
2. The current directory. 
3. The Windows system directory. 
See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-openfile#remarks)

Now, the current directory is something specific for every process, it can be configured on startup via parameters, or at runtime using `Directory.SetWorkingDirectory` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.2).

In you case, you need to set your working directory to where you web pages are.

Comment: You can use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location` to ensure it's the path your actual service DLLs are located in. Then you need no configuration at all.